# Logging a message when message discarding happens

Tags: nlog

From https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target#buffering-options, it says

> overflowAction - Action to be taken when in-memory-queue becomes full
> (Reached queueLimit). This means the background-writer is falling
> behind, and cannot keep up with the application-threads logging.
> Default: Discard Possible values:
>
> - Discard - The application-thread will discard logevent to avoid
>   becoming blocked or causing out-of-memory issues

Is it possible to log a message when this happens? It would be helpful to know that discarding is occurring.

I haven't found any questions on this topic in the NLog repo, on StackOverflow, or by doing general web searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) generates output when hitting the `queueLimit`.

But you can also try to hook into all targets of type `AsyncTargetWrapper`, and subscribe to the event-handler `LogEventDropped`.

```cs
foreach (var target in NLog.LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets)
{
    var asyncTarget = target as AsyncTargetWrapper;
    if (asyncTarget != null)
    {
        asyncTarget.LogEventDropped += // Something
    }
}
```